# How to select code in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: php, netbeans-8

I'm using netbeans 8.2 and can't figured out how to select code in curly braces in PHP files. The same in quotes. For example

```php
if($x == false)
```

I want quick select all line inside curly braces. The same in this line, how to select text only in quotations marks

```
echo 'Some wrong text here';
```

Also sometimes I need to select code between php tags `<?php code here ?>`.
Netbeans is a nice and cool IDE so I want to learn about features that can help in coding.

*Thanks in advance for your helping*

Answer (score 0):

So, if we write

```
if ($x = 'Something Wrong')
```

**ALT + SHIFT + .**     first select text in quotations marks, then select text in curly braces. Very nice.

```
echo 'Some wrong text here';
```

**ALT + SHIFT + .**   the same combination here, but it select quotes, too. 
Hoping my answer help someone :)

Answer (score -1):

Please specify you netbeans version.

Also try

```
Selecting Content Between Braces with Ctrl-Shift-[
```

For more information please visit

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/selecting-content-between-braces-with-ctrl-shift-

Comment: In the Q, OP specifies; `I'm using netbeans 8.2`, it does say the version in use